# Java is store wrongly spanish characters

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Java app that is loading a csv file with some content that I need to import in a MySQL database.

The issue is that for some spanish content like ñ or á é í ó ú, the app returns: `EL ESPA�OL`

The database Default Collection is `latin1 - default collection` I also try changing that to others like utf8, but the result was always the same.

The way I import the file is:

```
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file)));
            System.out.println("*** Importing file **** " + file);
            try {
                String line;
                int i = 0;
                while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    final String[] parts = line.split(",");
                    if(parts != null && parts.length > 0 && !parts[0].equalsIgnoreCase("")){
                        System.out.println("Line: " + i++ + " Text: " + line);
...
...
```

And when I do the request to the backend I sent the following headers:

```
accept: application/json
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: es-419,es;q=0.9,en;q=0.8
content-type: application/json
```

Comment: Try new InputStreamReader(new FileInputStream(file),"utf-8");

Answer (score 0):

Things to try :

### Recreate / Amend your table collations

Default collation is just that - a default. Your new tables take whatever the **current** default is unless you specify a collation.

If you don't recreate or amend your existing tables, they'll remain encoded in `latin1`.

### Check your JRE codepage

Are you running on Windows? What's your JRE default codepage set to?

It's been a while since I touched Java but I used to have terrible trouble with multi-byte chars because I would develop on Linux, and transfer the code to Windows and ... suddenly, funky � chars everywhere.

This may have changed at some point but on Linux and OSX, JREs start with the default encoding as UTF-8 .. and on Windows it uses the system code page. Which for me was cp1252 - decidedly not international.

Try printing this system property to the console to see if this is happening to you.

```java
System.getProperty("file.encoding")
```

You can change the value of this at startup with a `-D` argument as usual, e.g.

```sh
java -Dfile.encoding="UTF-8" -jar myJar.jar
```

... or, as @ControlAltDel says, always specify an encoding when you have the option in a stream API.